# Tags about registration and login

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Today, I manually removed the misspelled tag [registraton](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registraton) from two separate questions. While this was an easy thing with only two questions having the tag, either **making the misspelling a synonym** or deleting it and putting it on the blacklist will prevent it from happening again. And it is an easy misspelling to make and a hard one to notice when gazing at the word.

While I changed the tags, I also noticed that there is a [signup-signon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup-signon) tag. While we could make a case that if you nitpick it, [signup-signon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup-signon) can be used for questions which refer to both, and [registration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration) should be reserved to questions which are only about signon, it seems that the users are not nitpicking. They frequently use [signup-signon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup-signon) in combination with either [registration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration) or [login](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login). When it is used alone, such as in [Password field in cleartext](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6203/password-field-in-cleartext), one of the other two would obviously be also appropriate, in this case [registration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration).

So my second suggestion is to **burninate [signup-signon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup-signon)**, as its usage shows that it is redundant. The separate words, [signup](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup) and [signon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signon), could be created as new tags and be made synonyms of [registration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration) and [login](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login) respectively. Simply making the double tag a synonym does not seem possible, as it is usually applied to questions which refer to only one of the two concepts.

It would make sense to also manually assign either [login](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login) or [registration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration) to questions which have [signup-signon](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signup-signon) before burninating. I'm extrapolating this to touch 30 to 35 questions. If they are considered too many to bump, maybe at least do it for the 3-4 questions which have no other tag applied.

---

**Update** I went and manually edited 7 questions which had no tag at all beside [signup-signon]. I also checked the search syntax and noticed that you can exclude a tag :) so now I know that we have exactly 45 questions left which have [signup-signon] but neither [registration] nor [login]. We could either

- simply burninate the tag and accept that 45 questions will have inferior tagging
- gradually edit the 45 questions by hand, so we get only a few bumps per day, then burninate
- do a big bang edit action and live with the front page being overtaken for a few hours. The initial disruption shouldn't last too long, 45 questions are quickly edited and we get many other bumps from normal activity. But of course, people will start reanswering, so the results will probably linger for days.
- only manually edit the questions which need [login](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login) instead of [registration](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration). From my experience with the first 7, I expect them to be less than half. Then ask the team if they can automatically replace the tag for the others without bumping.

Which alternative is the best? Or is there a solution I've overlooked?

Comment: Agreed that signup-signon needs to die and registration/login are enough...not sure the best way to go about this though. Not all those signup signon questions have the relevant other tag and it's too much of a mess to alias the full set to one or the other. It'd be a ton of bumps to manually correct 'em beforehand too.

Comment: @BenBrocka I manually counted that 16 out of the first 50 signup-signon questions don't have one of the other tags. There are 98 questions in total. Seeing that there is no automatic way to decide which ones of them need [login] and which ones [registration], maybe we should bite into the sour apple this time and live with the 30+ expected bumps. We can space them through several days, so only 5 or so are bumped per day.

Comment: Just a sidenote: I personally against synonymizing misspelled tag, since that's not the purpose of tag synonymization (because it implicitly encourages users to use that tag). Let the misspelled tags be burnt naturally (blacklist is a bonus).

Comment: @AndrewT. as far as I remember, the synonym can't be "used" - the moment a synonymized tag is applied to a new question, it automatically gets replaced with the synonym master. If this is the case, a synonym is better for a misspelling, because then the user can post the question without a big red "tag blacklisted" in his face, and the question is still perfectly findable.