# Make the experience tag intrinsic

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-blacklist-request

I was [retagging "signup-signon" questions](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1887/tags-about-registration-and-login), so paying more attention to tags than usual. And so I noticed the tag [experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience).

I don't see a use for it other than indicate that the question is about user experience, which is nonsensical on this site. Indeed, when I looked over the questions tagged with it, I saw no value of having it there.

My suggestion is that it should be handled by the team [in the same way as the "user experience" tag was handled](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/should-we-get-rid-of-the-user-experience-tag).

Answer (score 3):

i agree with you.  in fact, it's worse that being merely redundant on the site...it provides a seemingly-sanctioned way for users to be sloppy with tagging ("oh, i can just use `experience`").

if there's resolution here i'm happy to retag the questions...there aren't too many of them.

Comment: Thank you for offering to help. But I don't think a manual retag is a good solution. The team can put it on a special list such that it can never again be used on a question asked on this site, while a manual retagging allows users to continue applying it to future questions.

Comment: @RumiP. If all the tags are removed the tag will be automatically removed after some time (and therefore not be able to be used unless it's created again)

Comment: @ZachSaucier yup, but this is the kind of tag which has the risk of getting created over and over again, unlike a, say, typo or off-topic term. And we know that we will not need it in the future. This is exactly the kind of situation blacklisting and intrinsic lists were made for, so it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that "experience" as a tag is problematic, I'd argue that there are occasions when we want to discuss the emotional aspects of a user interface.

For example, we prototyped a design and then user tested it .. although we had a usability 100% success rate, it was apparent from comments that users were left anxious at the end.

So, since "experience" is too broad a term (and should be removed as a tag when used in that broad sense), we still need an alternative term for the (rare) more specific uses.

"emotion" is not it though, as that isn't quite right if the question is about (say) making a UI "approachable"

Comment: Good point. "emotional-response" or "affective-response" maybe? The second is more accurate, but it is not what the site users are likely to think of, so I like the first one better. Or "subjective-reaction". Or simply "user-satisfaction".